# Encapsulation issues

Tags: php, oop, encapsulation

I have a tiny issues.

I have 3 classes:

```
Class Animal {
    public $dog;
    function __construct() {
        $this->dog = new Dog();
    }
}
Class Dog {
    public $scream;
    function __construct() {
        $this->scream = new Scream();
    }
}
Class Scream {
    public $scream;
    function __construct() {
    }
    public haaa(){
       return 'hello World';
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get `haaa()` function.. with

```
 $animal = new Animal();
 $animal->haaa();
```

If the function `haaa()` is into the `Dog` class.. it works fine.. Is it possible that we have a limit of deep encapsulation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example it would be:

`$animal->dog->haaa();`

However, it might be best to change the design so that `Dog extends Animal`:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  public function scream(){
    // do stuff
  }
}

$dog = new Dog();
$dog->scream();
```

That's more semantic, since dogs belong to the animal "kingdom".